# How to feed different pad IDs to a collate function?

Tags: pytorch

I usually use a custom `collate_fn` and use it as an argument when defining my DataLoader. It usually looks something like:

```
def collate_fn(batch):
    max_len = max([len(b['input_ids']) for b in batch])
    input_ids = [b['input_ids'] + ([0] * (max_len - len(b['input_ids'])))]
    labels = [b['label'] for b in batch]
    return input_ids
```

As you can see, I'm using `0` for my padding sequence. What I'm wondering is, since language models and their tokenizers use different IDs for padding tokens, is there a way that I can make the `collate_fn` flexible to take that into account?

Comment: This may be a solution: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/supplying-arguments-to-collate-fn/25754/2

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make a workaround by making a Trainer class and making the `collate_fn` a method. After that I was able to do something like `self.pad_token_id = tokenizer.pad_token_id` and modify the original `collate_fn` to use `self.pad_token_id` rather than a hardcoded value.

I'm still curious if there's any way to do this while keeping `collate_fn` a top-level function though. For example if there would be any way to pass an argument or something.

```
<Original>

def collate_fn(batch):
    max_len = max([len(b['input_ids']) for b in batch])
    input_ids = [b['input_ids'] + ([0] * (max_len - len(b['input_ids']))) for b in batch]
    return input_ids

class Trainer():
    def __init__(self, tokenizer, ...):
        ...

    def train(self):
        train_dataloader = DataLoader(features, collate_fn=collate_fn, ...)

    ...


<Workaround>
class Trainer():
    def __init__(self, tokenizer, ...):
        self.pad_token_id = tokenizer.pad_token_id
        ...

    def collate_fn(self, batch):
        max_len = max([len(b['input_ids']) for b in batch])
        input_ids = [b['input_ids'] + ([self.pad_token_id] * (max_len - len(b['input_ids']))) for b in batch]
        return input_ids

    def train(self):
        train_dataloader = DataLoader(features, collate_fn=self.collate_fn, ...)

    ...
```